# How to match json objects having fields as URL

Tags: dsl, karate

I am having a GET request which returned response in following format:

```
 "http://wso2.org/claims/role": [

    Application/API_ADMIN_SSO",
  ],

  "http://wso2.org/claims/applicationtier": "Unlimited",
  "http://wso2.org/claims/keytype": "PRODUCTION",
  "http://wso2.org/claims/version": "v1",
  "iss": "wso2.org/products/am"
```

How do I match these fields because if I do

```
And match response.http://wso2.org/claims/applicationtier == "PRODUCTION"
```

It throws and error saying path does not exist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
* def response = { "http://wso2.org/claims/applicationtier": "PRODUCTION" }
* match response['http://wso2.org/claims/applicationtier'] == 'PRODUCTION'
```